# Google Script Failing on message variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have two scripts working on the same sheet, one works fine, the other fails every time. The catch? they're duplicates of each other, just pointing at different sheets.

The debuggers announce that the 'message' variable doesn't exist, but again, the first copy here works great, the second just never runs.

Posting below

Functioning:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var email = 'fakeemail@fake.com';
  var updater = Session.getActiveUser();
  var subject = 'Tracker Updated by ' + updater;
  var text = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    if(cell.indexOf('I')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var body = 'Page Updated for ' + message + ' by; ' + updater;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
}
;
```

and the failing one

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var email = 'fakeemail@fake.com';
  var updater = Session.getActiveUser();
  var subject = 'Tracker  Now Updated by ' + updater;
  var text = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    if(cell.indexOf('Votes!L')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('Votes!A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var body = 'Page Updated for ' + message + ' by; ' + updater;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
}
;
```

So what gives?

Comment: Are those two functions with the same name in the same Apps Script project? If so, that won't work for you. All `.gs` files in an Apps Script project share the same namespace. That means only one function exists, even if you have 30 with the same name written in your script files. Also note that you never declare a `message` variable, you just assign to it, and only if a condition is true. If the condition is false, then your script has problems because you ask it to use something it doesn't know about.

Comment: well that's interesting. They do have different .gs names, but I didn't know that was a thing.  
I think your second part of the comment maybe gets to the heart of the problem: is there a way I should declare it? I tried 'var message =' but that resulted in returning an email of 'Page Updated for undefined by; fakeemail@fake.com'